# Updated: How to invoke makefile of a child directory to create a consolidate .o file which can be linked :

Tags: c, makefile

I have a root directory and a child directory. I am planning to put the functions in child directory under `libfunc.o`

This `libfunc.o` should be merged along with other object files in top directory. But I am getting error:

```
 $make all
  cd folder; make libfunc.o
  make[1]: Entering directory `/home/Work/test_makefile/folder'
  cc -c -o func2.o func2.c
  cc -c -o func3.o func3.c
  func3.c: In function ‘set’:
  func3.c:3:25: warning: initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
  ld  -r -o libfunc.o func2.o func3.o
  make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/Work/test_makefile/folder'
 arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc -c -o hellofun.o hellofun.c  -I. -I./include
 arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc -c -o hellomake.o hellomake.c  -I. -I./include
 arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc hellofun.o hellomake.o folder/libfunc.o -o hm
 folder/libfunc.o: file not recognized: File format not recognized
 collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
 make: *** [hm] Error 1
```

Makefiles: toplevel

```
  1 CC=arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc
  2 LD=arm-linux-gnueabi-ld
  3 AR=arm-linux-gnueabi-ar
  4 CFLAGS=-I. -I./include
  5 SOURCES=hellofun.c hellomake.c
  6 OBJECTS=$(SOURCES:.c=.o)
  7 SUBDIR_OBJS=folder/libfunc.o
  8 TARGET=hm
  9 DEPS = hellomake.h
 10 
 11 %.o: %.c $(DEPS) $(SUBDIR_OBJS)
 12         $(CC) -c -o $@ $<  $(CFLAGS)
 13 
 14 folder/libfunc.o:
 15         cd folder; $(MAKE) libfunc.o
 16 
 17 clean:
 18         rm -rf *.o hellomake folder/*.o 
 19 
 20 all: $(SOURCES) $(TARGET)
 21 
 22 $(TARGET): $(OBJECTS)
 23         $(CC) $(OBJECTS) $(SUBDIR_OBJS) -o $@
 24
```

Makefile : Child

```
  1 SOURCES=$(wildcard *.c)
  2 OBJECTS=$(SOURCES:.c=.o)
  3 TARGET=libfunc.o
  4 %.o: %.c 
  5         $(CC) -c -o $@ $<  $(CFLAGS)
  6 
  7 clean:
  8         rm -rf *.o      
  9 
 10 
 11 $(TARGET): $(OBJECTS)
 12         $(if $(strip $(OBJECTS)),\
 13                       $(LD) $(LDFLAGS) -r -o $@ $(OBJECTS),\
 14                       rm -f $@; $(AR) rcs $@ )
```

~
~
~

Comment: Your linker doesn't like the `libfunc.o` you've built. You can a) fiddle with the `ld` command to make `libfunc.o` more presentable, b) fiddle with the linker command to tell it how to cope with `libfunc.o`, or c) (best option in my opinion) scrap `libfunc.o` entirely for some other kind of file like `libfunc.a`.

Comment: I figured out, I missed export CC in root makefile

Comment: That's true. Check my answer. You also need to export LD.

Comment: yes i just hurriedly wrote that on this page.

Answer (score 0):

There's more than one error here.  First, when asking questions please always provide the complete error message.  The `no rule to make target` error will print out *which* target it's trying to make; that's critical information for helping you.

Second, you reference a variable `SUBDIR_OBJS`, but that's never defined.  Plus you list that as a prerequisite for building other object files in the `%.o : %.c` rule: it's virtually never correct to list object files as prerequisites of other object files.

The top-level makefile does not run make in the `folder` directory, so no commands in that directory will be run automatically.  You'll have to go there and run `make` yourself by hand.

Also in `config.mk` you create a variable `merge_object` but in `folder/Makefile` you refer to a variable `merge_objects`, which is not the same variable.

Comment: Updated the question, corrected a few things but getting error

Comment: That's a totally different error.  As Twocode says, you have to export `LD` as well.  You're compiling with a cross-compiler (I assume) for ARM but then linking with the native linker.  Not gonna work.

Answer (score 0):

I missed export CC in root makefile

Answer (score 0):

1. I would suggest put on the *-Wall* option in your compiler options, so that you can have a better debug view of your compiling process.
2. The output *ld  -r -o libfunc.o func2.o func3.o* seems suspicious to me. Looks like The system used default linker rather than your cross-compile linker, which is *arm-linux-gnueabi-ld*. That might be a reason for the file not recognized.
3. As the error was file format not recognized, maybe you can check *file libfunc.o* output?
4. If you are having with LD, why not skip it and try other methods, like just *gcc -o hm* with all object files, or use *ar* to package the objects in subfolder.